# What does this thread context sturcture do? What's its purpose?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Extracted from the code for "Motion"

```
struct context {
char conf_filename[PATH_MAX];
int threadnr;
unsigned short int daemon;
char pid_file[PATH_MAX];

struct config conf;
struct images imgs;
struct trackoptions track;
struct netcam_context *netcam;
struct image_data *current_image;        /* Pointer to a structure where the image, diffs etc is stored */
unsigned short int new_img;

int locate;
struct rotdata rotate_data;              /* rotation data is thread-specific */

int noise;
int threshold;
int diffs_last[THRESHOLD_TUNE_LENGTH];
int smartmask_speed;

/* Commands to the motion thread */
volatile unsigned short int snapshot;    /* Make a snapshot */
volatile unsigned short int makemovie;   /* End a movie */
volatile unsigned short int finish;      /* End the thread */
volatile unsigned short int restart;     /* Restart the thread when it ends */
/* Is the motion thread running */
volatile unsigned short int running;
volatile int watchdog;

...
};
```

I'm guessing that a program in Linux clearly can't just have one single process, thus the need for "threads", just like java programs.

And a constant issue with threads is switching between them, this of course, can be done mostly by Linux OS if you want.

Therefore we need a context struct to keep all the data we need to perform such an operation and beyond — since running the so-said thread clearly requires a context struct to store all the vital information as well.

So eventually you could have an array of "context struct" like what's shown above, with each thread corresponding to a struct.

So here are my questions:

A. Am I right in make all the above assumptions? Or did I missed it by 100 miles? I get it that at certain point, these structs *ARE* threads, or at least a very important part of.

B. Besides keeping information crucial for running and switching threads, what else could this struct be purposed? I understand that the code is incomplete, so this is a rather open-ended question. Answers based on previous coding experiences is encouraged.

C. Is such a practice common? By "such a practice" I mean dividing your application into several threads, and use context structs to keep track of them?

Answer (score 0):

You use threads in programs that require processing of data in an asynchronous way however I'm not familiar with using context structs at least not in the application code.

That kind of information is only required by the kernel. On an application you use a pthread_t variable to keep the information regarding that thread.